# Which ORM should I use together with ServiceStack and an existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am currently developing a web service which provides basic CRUD operations on business objects. The service will be used by legacy applications which currently use direct database access.

I decided to use ServiceStack instead of WCF due to ServiceStacks great architecture.

However know I am trying to decide wether to use OrmLite, nHibernate or Entity Framework to access the existing legacy database.

Requirements for the ORM are as follows

- Support for joins
- Support for stored procedures

I already tried OrmLite (as it's fast and already included with ServiceStack). The only way I managed to join two tables was by using SQL (not an option). Is there any better way?

```
// @stackoverflow: This is my POCO DTO
public class Country
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Alpha2 { get; set; }

    public string Alpha3 { get; set; }

    public string ShortText { get; set; }

    public string LongText { get; set; }
}

public class CountryRepository : ICountryRepository
{
    // @stackoverflow: This is the query to join countries with translated names stored in another table 
    private const string CountriesSql =
        @"SELECT C.Id, C.Alpha2, C.Alpha3, L.ShortText, L.LongText FROM COUNTRY AS C INNER JOIN LOCALIZATION AS L ON C.LocId = L.Id WHERE (L.Lang_Id = {0})";

    private const string CountrySql = CountriesSql + " AND C.Id={2}";

    private IDbConnection db;
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

    private IDbConnection Db
    {
        get { return db ?? (db = DbFactory.Open()); }
    }

    public List<Country> GetAll()
    {
        return Db.Select<Country>(CountriesSql, 0);
    }

    public Country GetById(long id)
    {
        return Db.SingleOrDefault<Country>(CountrySql, 0, id);
    }
}
```

The example above shows one of the simple business objects. Most others require Insert, Update, Delete, multiple Joins, and Read with many filters.

Comment: I wonder why joins with sql is not an option?

Comment: Because I don't want to be dependent on the unterlying database. Some future scenarios include storage to a different RDBMS.

Additionally I fear to much manual SQL once I get to CRUD the big objects.

Comment: Support for joins and stored procedures. Both NHibernate and EF fit the bill. NHibernate has more features, but EF's linq support is much better and is somewhat easier to learn (imho). As you have _many filters_ maybe the way you intend to do that should be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you need are joins (lazy-loading or eager loading) and stored procedure support and want to **get setup quickly** then Entity Framework and nHibernate are great options. Here is a cool link about EntityFramework and the repository and unit of work pattern. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

If you are very concerned with **performance** and want more control over how your classes will look (ie **POCOs**) and behave then you can try something more lightweight like ORMLite or Dapper. These two are just thin wrappers with less features but they will give you the best performance and most flexibility -- even if that means writing some SQL every once in a while.

You can also use hybrid approaches. Don't be afraid to mix and match. This will be easiest when using POCOs.

I think the important thing is to **code for your current database and current needs**. However, to do so using proper interfaces so if the time came to switch to a different database or storage mechanism then you simply have to create a new data provider and plug it in.

Comment: I made some tests using a complex entity. EF5 is a little bit slower than OrmLite, but given our really complex legacy database I favor quick setup over performance. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Ormlite supports primitive Join functions using expressions. The new [JoinSqlBuilder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/JoinSqlBuilder.cs) class can help with this. For SPs, I have added a [new T4 file](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/T4/OrmLite.SP.tt) to generate corresponding c# functions. Currently the SP generation code supports Sql Server alone; if you are using any other db, you can easily add support for it.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider LLBLGen Pro -- it's got great support for database first design and also has designer tools that speed up getting started if you use nHibernate or EF.  But it is $$.
http://llblgen.com

As a follow up to this Matt Cowan has created an AWESOME template generator for building this sort of thing with LLBLGen.  Check out the blog post here:

http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2013/03/10/rest-api-with-llblgen-and-servicestack/

and demo here:

http://northwind.mattjcowan.com/

The demo is entirely autogenerated!

Answer (score 1):

Also check this comparison from an OO perspective between NHibernate 3.x and Entity Framework 5/6
http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2013/03/entity-framework-56-vs-nhibernate-3.html